# Python tuple wordle guesser <string> error

Tags: python, string, tuples

So, i'm making a wordle guesser.
I can't get the "if (deadwords) not in x:"
it's telling me to make it a string but as a string it doesn't function properly (forgets about words that have the letters) I believe its called a tuple, but i'm not sure how to use those...

Code:

```
list1 = [
lotta words (too many)
]

c = 0
deadwords = ("r","o","s","k","n")

for x in list1:
  if (deadwords) not in x:
    c += 1
    print(f"found: {x}")

print(c)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 2324, in <module>
      if (deadwords) not in x:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not tuple
```

Comment: Please post error messages as text.

Comment: Also, what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get a bunch of different words that could be the wordle word of the day.

Comment: What is `deadwords` supposed to do?

Comment: deadwords is letters that won't be in the word.

Comment: so it should take all the words and sort out the ones with those "deadwords"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map()` to determine whether each deadword is in a given word, then use `any()` to find if there is any deadword present in the word:

```py
list1 = [
"sleep",
"bbbbb"
]

c = 0
deadwords = ("r","o","s","k","n")

for word in list1:
  if not any(map(lambda x: x in word, deadwords)):
    c += 1
    print(f"found: {word}")

print(c)
```

Comment: I think his intentions were for the if statement to be reversed (to filter out those letters in deadwords)

Comment: I'm still getting words with the letters... ^correct

Comment: @Flukey add a `not` before the any()

Comment: Edited, thanks. I thought they wanted the words to remove for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `set` for this:

```py
word_list = ["hello", "world"]


deadwords = {"r", "o", "s", "k", "n"}
for word in word_list:
    if deadwords.intersection(word):
        print(f"deadword found in {word}")
```

The `deadwords.intersection(word)` will return an empty set if none of the letters in `deadwords` are in the `word`.

You can alter this code then to narrow down the possible guesses once you've found words to remove. You'd want to maintain a copy of `word_list` and modify it instead of the original, for example:

```py
word_list = [...]
dead_letters = set()

remaining = word_list.copy()
while not game_over:
    # guess word
    # validate guess
    # add bad letters to the dead_letters set

    remaining = [word for word in remaining if not dead_letters.intersection(word)]
```